# setText(String) method not setting the value in modify listener in swt

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a requirement like, if the value in text field is empty,
then that text field should be set with another value.

For that I added listener like this

```
 nameText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
  @Override
  public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
    boolean notBlank = StringHelper.isNotBlank(nameText.getText());
    if (!notBlank) {
     nameText.setText(getNewName());
    }
  }
});
```

In the code **getNewName()** method will return new value,  but f I debugg flow is coming to this method, but value is not setting to text field

Instead of **getNewName()** method , if I pass some TEST value, it is setting to textfield

I debugg the source code of setText() method there,

**int length = OS.GetWindowTextLength (handle);**

this method return length as 0, for **getNewName()** method,
this method return length some integer, for for some test value

Comment: why are you calling getText and setText on a method, rather than on a component?

Comment: which component? sorry I did not get you? @Stultuske

Comment: the actual field of which you are trying to get and set the text?
a JTextField, a JLabel, something like that, I suppose

Comment: Sorry, I corrected code, actually I am adding listener on the component only... nameText is a Text (in SWT)

Comment: did you check what getNewName() returns? if it is length 0, then it doesn't really return a text to set

Comment: I checked, getNewName() method giving correct value, even in the source code method in debug mothod showing correct value...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54270/discussion-between-naveen-kocherla-and-stultuske).